# Silverlight - Howto use the Action<T> Delegate as a method parameter

Tags: silverlight

I have a bunch of metadata that I want to load before I render any pages (the page content depends on the meta data). Looking at the Application_Startup method in the App.xaml.cs I can see that there is the line of code

```
WebContext.Current.Authentication.LoadUser(this.Application_UserLoaded, null);
```

This looks to be exactly what I want (the definition is:

```
public LoadUserOperation LoadUser(Action<LoadUserOperation> completeAction, object userState);
```

This method calls the "Action" when the operation is completed.  How can I implement a similar approach for my LoadMetaData() method?

**MetaDataClass**

```
public static class MetaData 
    {
        private static bool _modelEntitiesIsLoading; 
        private static TTASDomainContext _ttasContext;       

        static MetaData()
        {
            Initialize();            
        }

        private static void Initialize()
        {
            _ttasContext = new TTASDomainContext();

        }
public static void LoadData()
        {
            //Exit if currently loading, or there is no context
            if (_modelEntitiesIsLoading || _ttasContext == null)
            {
                return;
            }

            _modelEntitiesIsLoading = true;

            _ttasContext.ModelEntities.Clear();
            var q = _ttasContext.GetModelEntityQuery();
            _ttasContext.Load(_ttasContext.GetModelEntityQuery(), OnModelEntitiesLoaded, null);
        }

private static void OnModelEntitiesLoaded(LoadOperation<ModelEntity> loadOperation)
        {
            if (loadOperation.Error != null)
            {
                //raise an event... 

            }
            else
            {
                ModelEntities = loadOperation;


                _modelEntitiesIsLoading = false;                

            }
```

Comment: <Insert dismissive anti-silverlight joke here>

Comment: OK. Microsoft is lazy and Silverlight makes Macs crash :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, so Action is simply a shorthand for a `void` method taking one parameter of type `T`. It is defined as:

```
public delegate void Action<T>(T obj);
```

So when you define a function taking an Action as a parameter you can simply call it as though it is a delegate:

```
public void LoadMetaData (Action<MetaDataOperation> callback) {
 //method implementation
 callback(new MetaDataOperation());
}
```

In the above scenario `MetaDataOperation` could be any type you want.

Having said that, I get the feeling this might not answer your question. In that case could you provide more detail as to what the problem is?

**EDIT** Right, so `MetaDataOperation` in this case is some sort of parameter that you want passed from `LoadMetaData` method when it's complete. It is completely up to you as to what's in it. If you don't actually need it, you might as well not have it like so:

```
public void LoadMetaData (Action callback) {
 //method implementation
 callback();
}  


//Use of LoadMetaData 

public static void OnMetaDataFinished() {
  System.Diagnostics.Debug.Trace("Finished loading metadata");
}
WhateverClass.LoadMetaData(OnMetaDataFinished);

//OR lambda version
WhateverClass.LoadMetaData(()=>System.Diagnostics.Debug.Trace("Finished loading metadata"));
```

Comment: I want to call LoadMetaData(MethodToRunWhenFinished)

and then in the calling class have that method defined (rather than in the class where LoadMetaData is defined...

I think the main area for confusion for me is what the type MetaDataOperation IS, it is the name of the method I want to run, but I have to define something?